# Команда "Закрыть вкладку / страницу"

Tags: php, javascript

Как в PHP вызвать команду 'закрыть вкладку / страницу', после того, как форма `target="_blank"` отправит данные на определённую страницу, чтобы та, после получения формы - закрылась, и мы автоматически вернулись на ту страницу, с которой отправляли форму?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так действуют многие системы - типа OAuth.
Делается примерно так - родительское окно порождает дочернее окошко, там происходит магия обмена всякими интересными и не очень сведениями с сервером, проверяется ответ - если сервер удовлетворён как от десяти девствениц - тогда вызываем `window.close()` и окно закроется, вернётся на родительское окно.

Answer (score 3):

Совершенно верно - никак.
Php тут вовсе ни при чем, клиент и сервер - две разные вещи.
Закрыть окно можно после отправки можно, например вызвав callback, в котором будет

```
window.close()
```

но опять же на какую вкладку попадет пользователь после закрытия текущей вкладки определяется только настройками браузера.
В одном браузере может кинуть на реферера, во втором на последнюю в списке, в третьем на предыдущую.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<script>window.close()</script>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Правильный ответ - никак. Это делается не в php. Php на серверной стороне, а вкладки - на клиентской. Php ничего не знает про вкладки. А если знает - значит ему сказал кто-то,кто знает,например javascript. Сам php про вкладки узнать ничего не может.